# Connected subset of the circle path connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider a connected subset $X$ of the circle $S^1.$ Is $X$ path connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C \subseteq S^1$ be a connected set. Now if $C = S^1$, then $C$ is trivially path connected. Otherwise there exists $p \in S^1 \setminus C$. Now, take the stereographic projection $\varphi : S \setminus \{p\} \to \mathbb{R}$, which is a homeomorphism. Thus, $\varphi(C)$ is connected on $\mathbb{R}$, and so it is path connected: the only connected sets on the reals are the intervals. But then again $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, so $C$ was path connected to begin with.

Comment: However, what if there are multiple points missing? You can still show that the open subset is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: The only assumption here on $C$ is that it is connected, open or otherwise. We need to have a point outside of $C$ in order to have a homemorphism between a subspace of $S^1$ that contains $C$ (namely $S^1 \setminus p$) and $\mathbb{R}$. In conclusion, this means that connected sets on $S^1$ are always path connected.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help, Guido. To clarify one last point, it only matters that $C \subseteq S \setminus \{p\}.$ Since  $S \setminus \{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R},$ and is therefore path connected, $C$ must be path connected also.

Comment: You are mostly correct. The idea is that since $S \setminus p \simeq \mathbb{R}$, the connected subsets of each are in correspondence. But connected sets in the reals are path connected, and a homeo preserves that, so the connected sets of $S \setminus p$ are path connected themselves. In particular we can conclude that for $C \subseteq S \setminus p$. This is much stronger than saying $\mathbb{R}$ is path connected: every connected subset of it is as well!